# Eclipse Workspace not recognized after clean install

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

I just made a clean install, as I do every year, of my linux system (ubuntu) on my notebook. 
I just wanted to open-up eclipse from my (old) workspace, where all my code from the past 12 months is - but eclipse doesn't show a single package!

My assumption is that I used an older version of eclipse up until yesterday before the clean install, and that the version I installed today is newer, thereby doesn't recognize my worksapce(s!). Is this assumption correct? if so, Does anyone know how I can figure out which version of Eclipse I was using when working on the old Workspace, so that I can download that exact same version again?
The absolut worst-case scenario would be to c/p all classes and packages manually into the new eclipse, but it's over a 1000 classes - so that might be too time-consumming.

An help would be greatly appreciated, since there actually are 2 projects from work in those workspaces... ^^

Comment: Newer versions of Eclipse usually work fine with older workspaces. Are you sure all the hidden files are there (file names starting with '.')?

Comment: navigating through the terminal, it seems that ls -a does actually display all the required files...

Comment: Try 'File > Refresh'

Comment: no luck there .. And I just saw that the version that was supposedly the current one is actually version 3.XX, from 2012. DL updates right now...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after Downloading Eclipse Mars, I found a solution. Although switching workspaces, or even importing the old workspaces didn't work, I found out that if I started eclipse from the old workspace, even though package explorer would stay empty, it would suffice to define a new java project with the exact same name of one of the projects inside the old workspace, for eclipse to instantly load-up the docs contents.
This not as much a solution, then a work-around... but still, fixed the problem!